# Unable to update the page layout for our enterprise wiki pages using sharepoint workflow 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, page-layout, workflow2013

I have a SharePoint online enterprise wiki site collection. and i have provided a newer pagelayout and new content type. but i do not want to update all the wiki pages at-once. so i tried to create a SP 2013 workflow which runs on item update, to check if the page layout does not have the new page layout and update the page layout accordingly.

but i faced 2 issues:-

1. i can not search for the Page Layout inside the If statement. as it does not allow to reference a page layout using the name.
2. inside the Set item, the Page Layout is not available, as follow:-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OOTB SharePoint Designer Workflow doesn't give those options to update the page layout.

If you want to update the content type using MS flow, refer this [link](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Is-there-a-way-to-use-Flow-to-change-the-Content-Type-of-a/td-p/92803).

Other Approach:

[Change Page Layout Using CSOM With PowerShell in SharePoint Online](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/change-page-lauusing-csom-with-powershell-for-sharepoint-onl/)

Comment: ok thanks for the reply, but per your knowledge, does MS Flow support this scenario?

Comment: Kindly raise this as a new question. If my answer is helped you kindly upvote it and Mark it as answer, so that it will help others too

Comment: Did you find any other approach??

Comment: If i find another approach i would not have ask this question... so not seems workflow does not support such an update

Comment: Ok ok. I thought of asking, after posting this question, did you find any other approach to fulfill the need?

Comment: If you find my answer useful, kindly upvote and Mark it as answer, so that it will be helpful for others too.